# Linq returning multiple values in a group by, need only last modified

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following linq, I want the last product modified in the day, for example at the begginning of the day I have 2000 products (`CajasDia`), but at noon I have only 500 products (`CajasDia`), this linq is giving me the full list of modifications of the products in the day, I want only the last record of the modified product (only the 500)

This involves 3 tables, `Producto` (products), `ProductoSubRegion` and `SubRegion`, a there are a lot of products containing in a region and a region contains a lot of products.

This is the relation between the tables: 
`Producto` 1..* `ProductoSubRegion` *..1 `SubRegion`

```
List<ProductoAgr> _productos = 
        (from p in db.ProductoSubRegion.Include("Producto")
        orderby p.Fecha descending
        where p.SubRegion.IDSubRegion.Equals(
           (from c in db.Cliente
            join v in db.Vendedor
            on c.IDVendedor equals v.IDVendedor
            where c.IDCliente.Equals(_IDCliente)
            select c.Vendedor.SubRegion.IDSubRegion).FirstOrDefault()) &&
            (p.Fecha >= today && p.Fecha < tomorrow)
        group p by new
        {
            p.Producto.IDProducto,
            p.Producto.Nombre,
            p.Producto.Precio,
            p.Producto.Descripcion,
            NombreProducto = p.Producto.TipoProducto.Nombre,
            p.Fecha,
            p.CajasDia
        } into ps
        select new ProductoAgr()
        {
            IDProducto = ps.Key.IDProducto,
            Nombre = ps.Key.Nombre,
            Precio = ps.Key.Precio,
            Descripcion = ps.Key.Descripcion,
            NombreProducto = ps.Key.NombreProducto,
            CajasDia = ps.Key.CajasDia,
            Fecha = ps.Key.Fecha
        }).ToList();
return View(_productos);
```

This is what I'm getting, I should be getting only one record, the 1496 value for the product1

[image: My error]

Comment: I guess the values `p.Fecha` and `p.CajasDia` differ for the "duplicate" rows.

Comment: I don't follow you, but I want only one record of the `p.CajasDia`, which I want to get by ordering the `p.Fecha` and getting the last modified...

Comment: Oh I got it, I removed the `p.Fecha` and `p.CajasDia` from the `groupby` but now I'm getting only the first record, not the last one, it's like the orderby is not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I split the linq into two linqs, its working, but it would be good to have only one, since it could improve the performance...

For anyone having a similar problem, a short explanation, the first linq gets all the products of the day that belongs to a `Region` order by `Fecha` (which is a date value); the second linq group the values into the unique values, such as ID of the product, name, price and description.

Hope it helps someone else.

```
List<ProductoSubRegion> _subregion = (from p in db.ProductoSubRegion.Include("Producto")
                                      where p.SubRegion.IDSubRegion.Equals(
                                          (from c in db.Cliente
                                           join v in db.Vendedor
                                           on c.IDVendedor equals v.IDVendedor
                                           where c.IDCliente.Equals(_IDCliente)
                                           select c.Vendedor.SubRegion.IDSubRegion).FirstOrDefault())
                                           && (p.Fecha >= today && p.Fecha < tomorrow)
                                      select p).OrderByDescending(y => y.Fecha).ToList();

List<ProductoAgregar> _productos = (from t in _subregion
                                    group t by new
                                    {
                                        t.Producto.IDProducto,
                                        t.Producto.Nombre,
                                        t.Producto.Precio,
                                        t.Producto.Descripcion,
                                        NombreProducto = t.Producto.TipoProducto.Nombre
                                    } into ps
                                    select new ProductoAgregar()
                                    {
                                        IDProducto = ps.Key.IDProducto,
                                        Nombre = ps.Key.Nombre,
                                        Precio = ps.Key.Precio,
                                        Descripcion = ps.Key.Descripcion,
                                        NombreProducto = ps.Key.NombreProducto,
                                        CajasDia = ps.Select(u => u.CajasDia).FirstOrDefault(),
                                        Fecha = ps.Select(u => u.Fecha).FirstOrDefault(),
                                    }).ToList();
return View(_productos);
```

The main difference is the place where I use the `orderby`, but I couldn't find an answer...